# How to execute a define inside a macro in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write a macro to generate Church encodings I have this so far

```lisp
#lang racket

(define-syntax data
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(data _ (ctr args ...) ...)
     (let ((_ctrs (map car '((ctr) ...)))
            (_args '((args ...) ...)))
        (map
           (lambda (i)
             (let ((_ctr (list-ref _ctrs i))
                   (_args (list-ref _args i)))
               `(define (,_ctr ,@_args) (lambda (,@_ctrs) (,_ctr ,@_args)))))
           (range 0 (length _ctrs))))
     ]
    ))

(pretty-print (data option (some x) (none))
```

Which outputs

```
(data option (some x) (none))

=> ((define (some x) (lambda (some none) (some x)))
    (define (none) (lambda (some none) (none))))
```

The output is good, but the defines are not being executed.

Now I want to execute these `define`s so that the functions are defined at top level

I tried this

```
(define-syntax data
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(data _ (ctr args ...) ...)
     `(let ((_ctrs (map car '((ctr) ...)))
            (_args '((args ...) ...)))
        ,@(map
           (lambda (i)
             (let ((_ctr (list-ref _ctrs i))
                   (_args (list-ref _args i)))
               (define (,_ctr ,@_args) (lambda (,@_ctrs) (,_ctr ,@_args)))))
           (range 0 (length _ctrs))))
     ]
    ))
```

But I get this error

```
(data option (some x) (none))

Error: struct:exn:fail:syntax

begin (possibly implicit): the last form is not an expression
  at: (define ((unquote _ctr) (unquote-splicing _args)) (lambda ((unquote-splicing _ctrs)) ((unquote _ctr) (unquote-splicing _args))))
  in: (begin (define ((unquote _ctr) (unquote-splicing _args)) (lambda ((unquote-splicing _ctrs)) ((unquote _ctr) (unquote-splicing _args)))))
```

I tried `(expand #'(data option (some x) (none)))` to debug but got the same error. I'm new to Racket, any advice on the macro debugging flow is welcome!!

---- Update

I have this macro now, it seems closer to what I need

```
(define-syntax data
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(data _ (ctr args ...) ...)
     #'((define (ctr) (lambda (ctr ...) (ctr args ...))) ...)
     ]
    ))
```

But still if I remove the `#'` I get

```
define: not allowed in an expression context
  in: (define (some) (lambda (some none) (some x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it, I need a  `(begin` here how I did it

```
(define-syntax data
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(data _ (ctr args ...) ...)
     (begin 
       (define (ctr args ...) (lambda (ctr ...) (ctr args ...)))
       ...
       )
     ]
    ))

(data option (some x) (none))

((some 1)
 (lambda (x) (format "is some ~a" x))
 (lambda () "is none")) ;; "is some 1"
```

Comment: Yep, `begin` is the correct construct to use. In this context, `begin` splices its content outside.